# Error occured when using HDFS to store the data of HBase

Tags: hadoop, hbase

When I set **hbase.rootdir** configuration in hbase-site.xml to local filesystem like **file:**//hbase_root_dir_path, hbase worked OK.But when I change it to **hdfs:**//localhost:9000/hbase, hbase was also OK at the beginning. **After a short time(usually a few seconds)**, however, it didn't work.I found the HMaster stopped with jps command.Of course I could not open the localhost:60010 web page.I read the log, and found sth wrong like the following:

```
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.server.PrepRequestProcessor: Got user-level KeeperException when processing sessionid:0x13e35b26eb80001 type:delete cxid:0x13 zxid:0xc txntype:-1 reqpath:n/a Error Path:/hbase/backup-masters/localhost,35320,1366700487007 Error:KeeperErrorCode = NoNode for /hbase/backup-masters/localhost,35320,1366700487007
INFO org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Opening socket connection to server localhost/127.0.0.1:2182. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error)
ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hbase.regionserver.handler.OpenRegionHandler: Failed open of region=person,,1365998702159.a5af90c23325829096517fb3b15bca17., starting to roll back the global memstore size.
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not instantiate a region instance.
WARN org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn: Session 0x13e35b26eb80002 for server null, unexpected error, closing socket connection and attempting reconnect
```

I use the pseudo-distributed mode of hbase in Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.
In my /etc/hosts, I have already changed the the IP of hostname to 127.0.0.1.And my hadoop safemode status if OFF.My hadoop version is 1.0.4 and my hbase version is 0.94.6.1(both are the latest stable release), the HBase Reference guide says hbase-0.94.x works fine with hadoop-1.0.x.

I think sth about the HDFS results the problem, because it really works with the local filesystem.By the way, there is a hbase-x.x.x-security release, what's the difference between it and hbase-x.x.x release and do I need to use the security release?

Comment: Is your NN running fine?Could you show me your logs and config files?

Answer (score 0):

Dit you set your Zookeeper quorum? It seems Zookeeper is trying to connect to your localhost.

Try setting the addresses of the machines you wan't to use using the `hbase.zookeeper.quorum` property in `hbase-site.xml`. Also, if you're not managing your own Zookeeper instance make sure that in `hbase-env.sh` this line isn't commented `export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true`.

Comment: I've set the **hbae.zookeeeper.quorum** to <code>localhost</code> and uncommented the **export HBASE_MANAGES_ZK=true**